# How to sort array values alphabetically and create sub array of values starting with same characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help to sort an array alphabetically and then combine them in sub arrays in JavaScript.

for example:

```
var arrayAll = ['1test', '100_test', 'andrew', 'andy', 'bittu', 'ben', 'bigB', 'chandan', 'chan', 'chetan', 'chaitali', ..............] ;
```

I need to convert this as below:

```
 var arraname = [['100_test','1test'],['andy','andrew'],[ 'ben',  'bigB','bittu'],[ 'chan','chandan', chaitali,'chetan'],[...]...];
```

What can be the Javascript logic for this?

Comment: Why should `1test` come before `100_test` or `bittu` before `ben` and `bigB`? Also read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). What have you tried?

Comment: apologies, these can be any string values not in sequenced,

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array and build groups based on the first character of every string.

```js
var array = ['1test', '100_test', 'andrew', 'andy', 'bittu', 'ben', 'bigB', 'chandan', 'chan', 'chetan', 'chaitali'],
    grouped = array
        .sort()
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            if ((r[r.length - 1] || [''])[0][0] === a[0]) {
                r[r.length - 1].push(a);
            } else {
                r.push([a]);
            }
            return r;
        }, []);
        
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For same upper/lower case letters, you could use a hash table for grouping and an case insensitive sorting.

```js
var array = ['1test', '100_test', 'Andrew', 'andy', 'bittu', 'ben', 'BigB', 'chandan', 'chan', 'chetan', 'chaitali'],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    grouped = [];

array
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
    })
    .forEach(function (a) {
        var key = a[0].toLowerCase();
        if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = [];
            grouped.push(hash[key]);
        }
        hash[key].push(a);
    });
        
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Its working fine for me but it contains more than 27 array elements, with Upper case and lower cased values are separated. what if I dont wish to use toLowerCase for my array elements any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort the array, then use reduce to group them based on their character value at index 0 and then filter out the empty array.

```js
var arrayAll = ['1test', '100_test', 'andrew', 'andy', 'bittu', 'ben', 'bigB', 'chandan', 'chan', 'chetan', 'chaitali'] ;

arrayAll.sort();

var result = arrayAll.reduce((r,a) => {
  let pos = a.charCodeAt(0) < 'a'.charCodeAt(0) || a.charCodeAt(0) > 'z'.charCodeAt(0) ? 0 : a.charCodeAt(0) % 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1;
  r[pos].push(a);
  return r;
}, Array.from({length:27}, _ => [] ));

let arrname = result.filter(x => x.length);

console.log(arrname);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you can create object (associative array),
then you can loop thru all your items in **arrayAll** and add them to object.
After that you can sort them by object keys and finaly create array as in this post: [convert Object {} to array [] in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/convert-object-to-array-in-javascript) , but leaving only **obj[key]**.
Note that obj[key] should be array that you have added elements to

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort your array and then [ASCII code tables](http://www.asciitable.com/) to create sub arrays and push them into a new array through a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> This is working and it's easier to understand

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7msaeyf/)

I'll try to optimize it, I am also a rookie in JS.

```js
function go(){
  var arrayAll=['1test', '100_test', 'andrew', 'andy', 'bittu', 'ben', 'bigB', 'chandan', 'chan', 'chetan', 'chaitali'];
arrayAll.sort();
  var arrayName = [];
  var temp =[];
  while(arrayAll.length)
  {
  temp=[];
    var startingChar = arrayAll[0].charAt(0);
    for(i=0;i<arrayAll.length;)
    {
      i=0;
      var pos = arrayAll[i].indexOf(startingChar);
      if( pos== 0)
      {
        var poppedChar = arrayAll.splice(pos,1);
        temp.push(poppedChar[0]);
      }
      else
      break;
    }
    arrayName.push(temp);
  }
  
  console.log(arrayName);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 go();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Each string is encapsuled within another array. This should not be the case.

Comment: @Xufox Sorry body, I didn't get that please explain

Comment: The first sub-array is `[
    [
      "100_test"
    ],
    [
      "1test"
    ]
  ]`, but should be `[
      "100_test",
      "1test"
  ]`.

Comment: Thank you buddy, Updated my answer. Now it's working fine. Thanks, Due to you I understood working of `splice( )`.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array first.

```
var array = ['1test', '100_test', 'andrew', 'andy', 'bittu', 'ben', 'bigB', 'chandan', 'chan', 'chetan', 'chaitali'];
var sortedArray = sorting(array);

function sorting(data) {
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    var nameB = b.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
    }
    // names must be equal
    return 0;
});
return data;
}
```

grouping according to alphabet

```
 var arrayName = createSection(sortedArray);

function createSection(dataAll) {
//according to name data is stored...
var temp = {}
var profile = [];
dataAll.forEach(function(element) {
    var name = element.toUpperCase();
    var id = name.charAt(0);
    if (!(temp[id] && temp[id].length)) {
        temp[id] = [];
    }
    temp[id].push(element);
});
 for (var k in temp){
   profile.push(temp[k]);
}
console.log(profile);
return profile;
}
console.log(arrayName);
```