# ERROR NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. JSON array is valid

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, multidimensional-array

I keep getting ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

```
 *ngFor="let spec of vehicleSpecs"
```

I've tried everything I can think of, including searching here.  It's a valid JSON array, so I *really* don't understand what's going on.

## view-specs.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    // get locally saved user information
    let user_id = window.localStorage.getItem('user_id');

    // construct the url
    let apiUrl = 'https://ridetrekker.com/api_v1/vehiclespecs/' + this.vehicle_id;

    // add the X-API-KEY HTTP header as required by API
    let key = window.localStorage.getItem('key');
    let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'X-API-KEY': key
        })
    };

    // do the ajax request
    this.http.get(apiUrl, options)
        .subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
            this.vehicleSpecs = result.data;


        });
}
```

## JSON data

```
 {
"status": true,
"message": null,
"data": {
    "0": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509824",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Millimeters",
        "unit_code": "MM",
        "measurement_type_title": "Free Play",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Clutch Cable",
        "system_title": "Controls",
        "value_a": 10,
        "value_b": 20
    },
    "1": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509827",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Millimeters",
        "unit_code": "MM",
        "measurement_type_title": "Free Play",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Throttle Cable",
        "system_title": "Controls",
        "value_a": 2,
        "value_b": 6
    },
    "2": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509830",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "RPM",
        "unit_code": "R/Min",
        "measurement_type_title": "RPM",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Idle Speed",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 830,
        "value_b": 1030
    },
    "3": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509851",
        "type_title": "Engine Oil Grades",
        "unit_title": null,
        "unit_code": null,
        "measurement_type_title": "Standard Grade",
        "type_item_title": "GN4 10W-40",
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": null,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "4": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509854",
        "type_title": "Engine Oil Grades",
        "unit_title": null,
        "unit_code": null,
        "measurement_type_title": "Premium Grade",
        "type_item_title": "HP4S 10W-30 Synthetic Oil",
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": null,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "5": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509707",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Liters",
        "unit_code": "L",
        "measurement_type_title": "Level",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 3.5,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "6": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509710",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Liters",
        "unit_code": "L",
        "measurement_type_title": "Level With Filter",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 3.7,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "7": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509716",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Foot Pounds",
        "unit_code": "FT LBS",
        "measurement_type_title": "Torque",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil Drain Bolt",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 22,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "8": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509719",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Foot Pounds",
        "unit_code": "FT LBS",
        "measurement_type_title": "Torque",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil Filter",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 19,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "9": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509866",
        "type_title": "Spark Plug Type",
        "unit_title": null,
        "unit_code": null,
        "measurement_type_title": "Type",
        "type_item_title": "DCPR6E",
        "spec_title": "Spark Plug",
        "system_title": "Ignition",
        "value_a": null,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "10": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509869",
        "type_title": "Spark Plug Type",
        "unit_title": null,
        "unit_code": null,
        "measurement_type_title": "Type",
        "type_item_title": "DCPR7E",
        "spec_title": "Spark Plug Alternate",
        "system_title": "Ignition",
        "value_a": null,
        "value_b": null
    }
}
```

}

Comment: your vehicleSpecs is an object not array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular 6.1 Use keyvalue pipe

```
*ngFor="let spec of vehicleSpecs.data | keyvalue"
```

For angular 2+

Try this

**TS**

```
 get key(){
    return Object.keys(this.results.data);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <div *ngFor="let k of key">
      <div>key: {{results.data[k].model_detail_id}}</div>
          <div>key: {{results.data[k].unit_title}}</div>
    </div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-r9dmnv

Comment: Adding '| keyvalue' results in a new error:  The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found

I am using Angular 6 and not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: keyvalue pipe only avilable 6.1

Comment: i have added alternative try that

Comment: Following your angular2+ example gives me TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Turns out I'm running Angular 5.2.11

Comment: please check that stackblitz example i have added solution for your json  data

Comment: It took some more digging, but this finally worked:

   this.vehicleSpecs = Object.keys(result.data).map(
                    key => ({type: key, value: result.data[key]}));

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular 6.1 it supports keyvalue pipe.

```
<p>Maps & KeyValue Pipe</p>
<div *ngFor="let item of vehicleSpecs.data | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value.model_detail_id}}</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding '| keyvalue' results in a new error: The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found I am using Angular 6 and not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: do ng --version and check u r using 6.1. If not. remove node_modules folder. Try these 2 commands 1) npm cache verify --clean 2) npm install

Answer (score 0):

As i see **`result.data`** is an **`object`** of **`objects`**, you need either an array or convert to array of objects.

if you are using latest version of angular, you can simply use the keyvalue pipe.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of vehicleSpecs.data | keyvalue">
```

Comment: So I tried doing that from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/convert-object-to-array-in-javascript but it makes it even worse

Comment: Adding '| keyvalue' results in a new error: The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found I am using Angular 6 and not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
vehicleSpecs=[]

for(let item in result.data)
  this.vehicleSpecs.push(item)
```

or use keyvalue pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of vehicleSpecs.data | keyvalue">
```

Comment: Adding '| keyvalue' results in a new error: The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found I am using Angular 6 and not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Json is not valid,

If you want to iterate using **ngFor** then the type of data must be array

valid json is like,

```
{
"status": true,
"message": null,
"data": [
    "0": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509824",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Millimeters",
        "unit_code": "MM",
        "measurement_type_title": "Free Play",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Clutch Cable",
        "system_title": "Controls",
        "value_a": 10,
        "value_b": 20
    },
    "1": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509827",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Millimeters",
        "unit_code": "MM",
        "measurement_type_title": "Free Play",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Throttle Cable",
        "system_title": "Controls",
        "value_a": 2,
        "value_b": 6
    },
    "2": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509830",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "RPM",
        "unit_code": "R/Min",
        "measurement_type_title": "RPM",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Idle Speed",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 830,
        "value_b": 1030
    },
    "3": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509851",
        "type_title": "Engine Oil Grades",
        "unit_title": null,
        "unit_code": null,
        "measurement_type_title": "Standard Grade",
        "type_item_title": "GN4 10W-40",
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": null,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "4": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509854",
        "type_title": "Engine Oil Grades",
        "unit_title": null,
        "unit_code": null,
        "measurement_type_title": "Premium Grade",
        "type_item_title": "HP4S 10W-30 Synthetic Oil",
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": null,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "5": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509707",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Liters",
        "unit_code": "L",
        "measurement_type_title": "Level",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 3.5,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "6": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509710",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Liters",
        "unit_code": "L",
        "measurement_type_title": "Level With Filter",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 3.7,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "7": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509716",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Foot Pounds",
        "unit_code": "FT LBS",
        "measurement_type_title": "Torque",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil Drain Bolt",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 22,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "8": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509719",
        "type_title": null,
        "unit_title": "Foot Pounds",
        "unit_code": "FT LBS",
        "measurement_type_title": "Torque",
        "type_item_title": null,
        "spec_title": "Engine Oil Filter",
        "system_title": "Engine - General",
        "value_a": 19,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "9": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509866",
        "type_title": "Spark Plug Type",
        "unit_title": null,
        "unit_code": null,
        "measurement_type_title": "Type",
        "type_item_title": "DCPR6E",
        "spec_title": "Spark Plug",
        "system_title": "Ignition",
        "value_a": null,
        "value_b": null
    },
    "10": {
        "model_detail_id": "1509869",
        "type_title": "Spark Plug Type",
        "unit_title": null,
        "unit_code": null,
        "measurement_type_title": "Type",
        "type_item_title": "DCPR7E",
        "spec_title": "Spark Plug Alternate",
        "system_title": "Ignition",
        "value_a": null,
        "value_b": null
     }
  ]
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but fixing it breaks an existing API which I don't have access to.

Comment: If you are using lodash then there is inbuilt method that helps to convert object to array whithout any hesistance like...... _.values(result.data);