# Convert object to array reactjs and ramda

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ramda.js

Given the following data:

```
    const state = {
        products: {

        newValues: {
          "1": {
            "product_id": 1,
            "name": "Product 1"
          },
          "2": {
            "product_id": 2,
            "name": "Product 2"
          },
        },
        newValuescat:{
          "61": {
            "category_id": 61,
            "name": "category name"
          }
        }
        }
}
```

I am new in react and ramda. How to use ramda and which function i have to use to convert in array.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.  First of all, it specifically asked how to do this in Ramda, with reference to React.  Second of all, it's not at all clear how and if the keys "1", "2", and "61" are meant to be handled, nor what is to be made of the nested structure of the original.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include the new shape you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I've stole some code from here: 
[convert Object {} to array [] in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/convert-object-to-array-in-javascript/44790922)

```
var obj = {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0}
var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return [Number(key), obj[key]];
});
```

This should do it!

Comment: Sorry actually i was bit confused. Now i have updated the question which i required.

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: @EdwardLynch if the question is a duplicate, please flag it to be closed rather than posting an answer.

Comment: On mobile, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you want.  But here's are two possible solution, based on my best guess:

```js
const makeArrays = R.evolve({products: R.map(R.values)})

const state = {"products": {"newValues": {"1": {"name": "Product 1", "product_id": 1}, "2": {"name": "Product 2", "product_id": 2}}, "newValuescat": {"61": {"category_id": 61, "name": "category name"}}}}

console.log(makeArrays(state))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

From the inside out, here's what it does:  [`R.values`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#values) is much the same as `Object.values`, taking an object, thought of as a list of key-value pairs, and returning a list of just the values.  Passing that to [`R.map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) and supplying that the `products` object, we map over the elements in `products`, replacing them with the call to `R.values` in each one.  Finally [`R.evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) takes a specification object that supplies functions to run on each of its keys, and transforms and object using those functions.

---

My second version is similar, still using `map(values)`, but using a slightly more standard tool than Ramda's `evolve`, known as lenses:

```js
const makeArrays = R.over(R.lensProp('products'), R.map(R.values))

const state = {"products": {"newValues": {"1": {"name": "Product 1", "product_id": 1}, "2": {"name": "Product 2", "product_id": 2}}, "newValuescat": {"61": {"category_id": 61, "name": "category name"}}}}

console.log(makeArrays(state))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

A Lens lets you focus attention on one part of a data structure, leaving the rest intact.  You can access the property with [`R.view`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#view), mutate the property with [`R.set`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#set), or adjust it with [`R.over`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over).  There are several functions that produce lenses.  Here we use [`R.lensProp`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp), which focuses attention on a named property of an object.

Lenses are a more widely recognized tool in the functional programming world than Ramda's more proprietary, `evolve`.  But they are designed for different things.  Lenses are meant to focus on a specific part of a structure, but to do anything you want with it, where `evolve` lets you adjust many parts of a structure, but doesn't offer plain access that lenses do.  Because you want only to adjust a single property, either approach will work here.

Answer (score 0):

The simple version is:

```
<div>{R.compose(
  R.values,
  R.map((item: any) => renderYourJsx(item))
 )(this.props.yourData)}</div>
```

`R.values` converts your object to an array, then use `R.map` to map over the array items. You can wrap both these in `R.compose` and pass your object directly to the compose function.