# Pushing items to an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following variable

```
var brands = [];
```

Which I need to populate with some data. The data is comming from an API. I use `Axios` to perform a `GET`.

```
getRemoteBrands() {
    axios
      .get("http://my-url")
      .then(response => {
        response.data.forEach(element => {
          var instance =
          {
            label: element.brand,
            value : element.brand    
          };
          this.brands.push(instance);
        });
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

The following error is show in developer tools

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at index.js:104
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:98
```

Obviously `brands` is not an `array`, but an object. How can I make this an `array`?

Comment: `var brands = [];` creates a *standalone* variable. `this.brands` is not a standalone variable, it's a property of `this`, which is something entirely different (which sounds to be `undefined`)

Comment: Wow. Javascript </3 Please post an answer and I'll accept that

Comment: The `this` at that point refers mostly to the `axios` one.

Comment: Please show a sample response object you get in response

Comment: please follow this link to convert object into array.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var brands = [];` creates a *standalone* variable. `this.brands` is not a standalone variable, it's a property of `this`, which is something entirely different (which sounds to be `undefined` in your case - you've never assigned anything to `this.brands` before).

Either refer to the standalone variable `brands` after creating it:

```
var brands = [];

class something {
  // ...
  getRemoteBrands() {
    var instance = {
      label: element.brand,
      value : element.brand    
    };
    brands.push(instance);
  }
}
```

Or create `this.brands` in the constructor, and refer to `this.brands`:

```
class something {
  constructor() {
    this.brands = [];
  }
  getRemoteBrands() {
    var instance = {
      label: element.brand,
      value : element.brand    
    };
    this.brands.push(instance);
  }
}
```