# Is it possible for a JS value to be an array and a function? Array.isArray(v) + typeof v === 'function'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible for a JS value to be an array and a function?

```
const isArrayAndFunc = v => {
  return Array.isArray(v) && typeof v === 'function';
}
```

could `isArrayAndFunc` ever return true for a value in JS?

I don't think it is, but just checking.

Comment: no, why do you think it may be possible?

Comment: The closest thing would be `const x = function(){}; Object.setPrototypeOf(x, Array.prototype);`, then `typeof x === "function" && x instanceof Array === true`, but `isArray` will still say `false`.

Comment: No.  A single object can't perform identically to both an array and a function.

Answer (score 1):

Might be considered cheating, but it would be possible to overwrite `Array.isArray` to implement your own logic:

```js
Array.isArray = () => true;
const isArrayAndFunc = v => {
  return Array.isArray(v) && typeof v === 'function';
};

console.log(isArrayAndFunc(() => 'foo'));
```

Internally, `Array.isArray`, in ES5, [checks](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2):

> If the value of the [[Class]] internal property of arg is "Array", then return true.

This is an *internal* property, which can't be modified:

> This specification defines no ECMAScript language operators or built-in functions that permit a program to modify an object’s **[[Class]]** or [[Prototype]] internal properties or to change the value of [[Extensible]] from false to true. Implementation specific extensions that modify [[Class]], [[Prototype]] or [[Extensible]] must not violate the invariants defined in the preceding paragraph.

In [ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isarray):

> 2. If argument is an Array exotic object, return true.
> 3. If argument is a Proxy exotic object, then
>
>    a. If the value of the [[ProxyHandler]] internal slot of argument is null, throw a TypeError exception.
>
>    b. Let target be the value of the [[ProxyTarget]] internal slot of argument.
>
>    c. Return IsArray(target).

For 2., there [doesn't look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527480/is-there-any-way-to-turn-an-existing-javascript-object-into-an-array-without-cre) to be any way to turn any object (or function) into an "Array exotic object". `setPrototypeOf` can be used to set the internal prototype of the function, but it still won't *actually* be an "Array exotic object".

```js
'use strict';
const fn = () => 'foo';
Object.setPrototypeOf(fn, Array);

const isArrayAndFunc = v => {
  return Array.isArray(v) && typeof v === 'function';
};
console.log(isArrayAndFunc(fn));
```

For 3, if the object being examined is a Proxy, then its `typeof` will be an `object`, not a function.

So unless you overwrite `Array.isArray` (or, overwrite/shadow `Array` itself), I don't think `isArrayAndFunc` could ever return `true`.

Comment: `Is it possible for a JS value to be an array and a function?` The question has nothing to do with your answer. Changing the function doesn't change the value

Comment: The question asks `could isArrayAndFunc ever return true for a value in JS?`, so I wrote my answer trying to describe how such a thing could (or couldn't) be possible. There are a few things one might *think* one might be able to do to the function to get the `isArrayAndFunc` to return `true`, but I don't think any of them pan out. Sure seems on-topic to me, given the question

Answer (score -1):

*Technically*, yes... but only if someone were to override the built-in `Array.isArray()` method. For example:

```
Array.isArray = () => true;
console.log( Array.isArray( 'foo' ) );  // true
console.log( Array.isArray( []    ) );  // true
console.log( Array.isArray( ()=>1 ) );  // true

const isArrayAndFunc = v => {
  return Array.isArray(v) && typeof v === 'function';
}
console.log( isArrayAndFunc( ()=>1 ) );  // true
```

So, yeah, it could... but unlikely?