# How to list of objects into list of arrays in js?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data `[{a:12,b:20},{a:20,b:123}]`

How I can convert this to `[[12,20],[20,123]]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an Object to an Array of key-value pairs in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an Object {} to an Array \[\] of key-value pairs in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Comment: That's not a dupe, guys - it's about converting `{a: 12}` into `["a", 12]` not into `[12]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) using [Object.Values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) as the mapping method:

```js
let input = [{a:12,b:20}, {a:20,b:123}];
let res = input.map(Object.values);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If you need to rely on order of the keys, then refer to **@MarkMeyer** answer, it can be more appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: This makes some assumptions about the key order doesn't it?

Comment: @MarkMeyer you are right, however he don't specify nothing about order and I was thinking more about a general approach (i.e when more keys can exists and the objects can have differents keys). I see too that your answer is more appropiated if he need ordering.

Comment: I will say the succinctness of it is very attractive.

Answer (score 4):

It's a pretty one-liner with some destructuring:

```js
let l = [{a:12,b:20},{a:20,b:123}]
let arr = l.map(({a, b}) => ([a, b]))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: As I say on my answer, this is a more appropriate approach if you need to rely on the order of the keys and deserves my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{a:12,b:20},{a:20,b:123}]
let result = []
data.forEach(d => result.push([d.a,d.b]))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the keys and loop it with your input variable. i have used map function to loop and get data in array format.

```js
var input = [{a:12,b:20},{a:20,b:123}];

var keys = Object.keys(input[0]);

var output = [];

keys.forEach(function(key){
output.push(input.map((item) => item[key]))
})
console.log(output)
```