# How to send data in array format instead of json format(from an observable)

Tags: angular, observable, lodash

I am trying to extract my daily hours from my app using an Observable and process this data as an array,but right now I get this data in JSON format.

calculation.service.ts:

```
items: { [key: string]: IItem } = {};
private update = new Subject<void>();
getDailyHours(): Observable<{ [key: string]: string }> {
    return this.update
      .map(() =>
        _.chain(this.items)
          .values()
          .groupBy("date") //date is of type string
          .mapValues(items => this.timeService.format(_.sumBy(items, "spent")))
          .value()
      )
      .distinctUntilChanged(_.isEqual);
  }
```

overview.component.ts

```
dailyHours: { [key: string]: string } = {};
ngOnInit(){
this.calculationService.getDailyHours().subscribe(s => {
      this.dailyHours = s;
      console.log(this.dailyHours);
    });
}
getHours(date: string) {
    const sum = this.dailyHours[date];
    return sum === "0m" ? "" : sum;
}
```

dailyHours gets printed in console like this :

```
{08.04.2018: "0m", 09.04.2018: "0m", 10.04.2018: "0m", 11.04.2018: "0m", 12.04.2018: "0m", …}
```

This makes it difficult to parse  my data when given dynamic data.(fx: if i go 1 week back my json will have different key values "01.04.2018", ..."07.04.2018")

How can I modify my observable to output an array instead of JSON ?

Comment: What format do you want ?? This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapKeys Check this