# How to convert an array object to an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have an array object now. The function should return an array of arrays of all object values. Where is the mistake?

```js
const car = [
  {  
    "name":"BMW",
    "price":"55 000",
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mitsubishi",
    "price":"93 000", 
    "constructor":"Bar John",
    "door":"3",
    "country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mercedes-benz",
    "price":"63 000", 
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  }
 ];

function cars(car){
  return car.map(function(key) {
    return [[key]];
  });
}
console.log(cars(car));
```

Comment: `key` references each object in your array, so you go from this: `[{}, {}, ...]` to this `[[[{}]], [[{}]], ...]`. Show the structure you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an Object {} to an Array \[\] of key-value pairs in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return the values of the object.

```js
function cars(car){
    return car.map(Object.values);
}

const car = [{ name: "BMW", price: "55 000", country: "Germany", security: "Hight" }, { name: "Mitsubishi", price: "93 000", constructor: "Bar John", door: "3", country: "Japan" }, { name: "Mercedes-benz", price: "63 000", country: "Germany", security: "Hight" }];

console.log(cars(car));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the individual array object in another array so it becomes `[[{object}]]`, simply `map` to a new array of `Object.values` of the inner objects.

```js
const car = [
  {  
    "name":"BMW",
    "price":"55 000",
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mitsubishi",
    "price":"93 000", 
    "constructor":"Bar John",
    "door":"3",
    "country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mercedes-benz",
    "price":"63 000", 
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  }
 ];

function cars(car){
  return Array.from(car, Object.values)
}
console.log(cars(car));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `[[key]]` to `[key]`

```js
const car = [
  {  
    "name":"BMW",
    "price":"55 000",
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mitsubishi",
    "price":"93 000", 
    "constructor":"Bar John",
    "door":"3",
    "country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mercedes-benz",
    "price":"63 000", 
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  }
 ];

function cars(car){
  return car.map(function(key) {
    return [key];
  });
}
console.log(cars(car));
```