# Is it possible to change from JSON object to JSON array in controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

Im using SlickGrid and was tying to add data from grid to the DB when the user press the Enter key. It is sendig and JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`)  and I need it as an array since im using type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. Is its possible, in the controller , change it to a JSON array ?
The data is obtained from the grid itself.
Thanks in advance!

I've seen some similar situations but Im still gettint the error :

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DAL.SlickGridTest]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

this is my action `public ActionResult EditGridEnter(string mydata)`
and this is my `jquery $.post`

```
grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function(e) {
  var keyPressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (keyPressed == 13) {
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(item);
    $.post("/SlickGridTest/EditGridEnter", $("input[name=mydata]").val(myJSON));
  }
});
```

This is what comes from item  :

```
var idData = jsonResult[key].id + 1;
var item = { "id": idData, "t_nome": "", "t_prof": "", "t_data": "", "t_morada": "", "t_percCompleto": "" };
```

all data comes from the grid in slickgrid

This is how I deserialize the object:

`var slcgrd= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SlickGridTest>>(mydata);`

I expect to get values as an array (e.g. `[1,2,3]`) and im getting as `object ( Object {id: 43, t_nome: "name name", t_prof: "prof", …} )`

Comment: what's in `item`?

Comment: Your MVC action takes a string, so your question is missing information concerning ***how*** you are attempting to deserialize that string to your desired type, and what that type is. You also don't describe what you're sending (i.e. the value of `item` in the JS code)

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio updated the code, you can see it now!

Comment: `var array = Object.keys(item).map(function(key) {  return [Number(key), item[key]]; });` as seen on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript

Comment: @spender udpate with the deserialized ! sorry about that

Comment: or, if you only need an array of values (without preserving the object's keys) just use: `var array = Object.values(item);`

Comment: So is type `SlickGridTest` the same shape as that JS variable, `item`?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio ok, now is in an array! My question now is : can the controller recieve an array as argument?
Im kinda fresh to ASP.NET  and self-learning :c

Comment: @spender  yes ! But the `SlickGridTest` is my DAL class, and `item` is where the data the user introduced in the grid goes. Then is passes and comes to the controller as JSON object ! But my `SlickGridTest` needs an array .
( if I get your question right)

Comment: uhm, there's no `list` data type in javascript, but a simple array like that is basically a list... hope asp.net likes it

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio hum , the controller does not get the data ! it recieves `mydata Count = 0` :/

Comment: Isn't it then as simple as wrapping the item up in an array? `var myJSON = JSON.stringify( [item] );` ?

Comment: ... or deserializing a single object instead of a list? `var slcgrd= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlickGridTest>(mydata);` ?

Comment: @spender I've done deserializing a simple object instead of list! Didnt update yet because was at lunch break!
But thanks! Even your first comment its pretty simple and more practice, since I dont need to change the controller! Put as answer so I can accept! and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears you are trying to deserialize to a `List<SlickGridTest>`. When deserializing to a list, the deserializer expects to see a JSON array structure. As such you have two choices.

Either send an array with a single item:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify( [item] );
```

or change your controller deserialization to expect a single item instead:

```
var slcgrd= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlickGridTest>(mydata);
```