# React PropTypes - Allow only one of objects values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Consider having a key and value map object like below:

```
export const PlaceholderVisibility = {
  Always: undefined,
  Never: null,
  OnFocus: true,
  OnBlur: false
}
```

How would you use `PropTypes` to only allow values specified in the existing object?

Here is what I tried:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
export const myTypes = {
  // ...
  visibility: PropTypes.oneOf(PlaceholderVisibility)
}
```

But I am currently using `PropTypes.bool` as that seems to work for this situation, but still, that would not work when for example one of the values was of type string.

Comment: just extract values (or keys) from object into an array

Comment: @xadm, Would something like `PropTypes.oneOf( [ ...PlaceholderVisibility ] )` do that for me? (I mean, especially for objects with more key and values, it would be troublesome to do that manually)

Comment: rather sth like `Array.from()`, `object.values` (or keys) ... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

To allow only one of `object` values in `React PropTypes` - you can use `PropTypes.oneOf` with `Object.values()` like so:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const PlaceholderVisibility = {
  Always: 'always',
  Never: 'never',
  OnFocus: 'on-focus',
  OnBlur: 'on-blur'
}

export const myTypes = {
  // ...
  visibility: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(PlaceholderVisibility))
}
```

**Note**, the statement above is equal to just this:

```
export const myTypes = {
  // ...
  visibility: PropTypes.oneOf([
   'always',
   'never',
   'on-focus',
   'on-blur'
  ])
}
```

So, it's better to have `values` in your object quite a unique to avoid misusages. E.g., if someone passed directly value like `'always'` string - react won't complain.