# Create multidimensional array in a loop with auto index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'd like to create a multidimensional array using a loop in jQuery/JS. Is it possible to use the next available key instead of setting it manually?

jsonFromPhp contains something like this:

```
0 {first_name: "Tom", last_name: "Smith", location: "London"}
1 {first_name: "Max", last_name: "Muster", location: "Zurich"}
2 {first_name: "Joanne", last_name: "Kate", location: "London"}
...
```

Here is the loop:

```
jsonFromPhp.forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row['location'] == 'London') {
        firstKey = 0;
    } else {
        firstKey = 1;
    }

    row.forEach((singleData, n) => {
        pushedArray[firstKey][] = singleData[n]; // doesn't work, I have set the index manually (with i for example). But then I have an array like 0, 2, 5 etc. and I need 0, 1, 2
    });
});

Expected Result:
0 Array (1)
    0 ["Tom", "Smith", "London"] (3)
    1 ["Joanne", "Kate", "London"] (3)
    ...
1 Array (1)
    0 ["Max", "Muster", "Zurich"] (3)
    ...
```

and not (if I set pushedArray[firstKey]**[i]**)

```
0 Array (1)
    0 ["Tom", "Smith", "London"] (3)
    2 ["Joanne", "Kate", "London"] (3)
    ...
1 Array (1)
    1 ["Max", "Muster", "Zurich"] (3)
    ...
```

or

```
0 Array (1)
    0 ["Tom", "Smith", "London", "Joanne", "Kate", "London"] (6)
1 Array (1)
    1 ["Max", "Muster", "Zurich"] (3)
    ...
```

Comment: `(row['location'] == 'london'` is case sensitive and your value is `London`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for the hint, updated the code. This is just a shorter version of my code so if there are still typing errors, I'm sorry :).

Comment: *use the next available key* that's what `.push()` does - `pushedArray[i].push(singleData[n])`

Comment: @freedomn-m But this inserts all rows in one. Take a look at the expected output and what I don't expect/need. :) Basicly I need an head array and a row array with all values.

Comment: I see what you mean by "inserts all rows in one" with a simple .push: https://jsfiddle.net/5ezL10y9/1/ - need to create the sub-array first and then push to that (2nd dimension), not the 1st dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use the next available key

To generate array indices automatically, the easiest way is with

```
arr.push(value)
```

this is the same as

```
arr[arr.length] = value
```

The issue in this question is for multi-dimensional array to ensure you are "pushing" into the correct dimension.

In this case, the 1st dimension ("london") is always 2 long, so we can simplify this by creating the array up-front:

```
var arr = [[],[]];
```

which creates an array with 2 entries, both of which are themselves empty arrays (2 dimensions).

The code then determines whether to use 0 or 1, that's fine - the next dimension is then for each row / object in the source and under that is where the data goes, giving:

```js
var source = [
{first_name: "Tom", last_name: "Smith", location: "London"},
{first_name: "Max", last_name: "Muster", location: "Zurich"},
{first_name: "Joanne", last_name: "Kate", location: "London"}
];

// create 1st dimension (arr[0], arr[1]) initially
var arr=[[],[]];

// loop through each source row
source.forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row['location'] == 'London') {
        firstKey = 0;
    } else {
        firstKey = 1;
    }
    
    // add a subdimension for this row
    var rowArr = [];
    for(var k in row)
    {
        // add the properties into the subdimension
        rowArr.push(row[k]); 
    }
    
    // add the object->array into the 0/1 top-level array
    // using "the next available index"
    arr[firstKey].push(rowArr);
        
});
console.log(arr);
```

This can or course be substantially reduced (eg using `.map` and `?:` for location), but this keeps the closest to your original code, changing only the parts relevant to the question.

---

**Reducing your code using `.forEach`**

Using [object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38824395/2181514) and the same principle of creating the base array up-front you can use `?:` to reduce the location index:

```
firstKey = row['location'] == 'London' ? 0 : 1
```

We can reduce your code to a one-liner (split for clarity):

```js
var source = [
{first_name: "Tom", last_name: "Smith", location: "London"},
{first_name: "Max", last_name: "Muster", location: "Zurich"},
{first_name: "Joanne", last_name: "Kate", location: "London"}
];

var arr = [[],[]];

source.forEach((row) => 
    arr[row['location'] == 'London' ? 0 : 1].push(
        Object.keys(row).map(
            (key) => row[key]
        )
    )
);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work for more than 2 locations as well as no need to care about what values come for `location` from backend.

```js
const arr = [{
  first_name: "Tom",
  last_name: "Smith",
  location: "London"
}, {
  first_name: "Max",
  last_name: "Muster",
  location: "Zurich"
}, {
  first_name: "Joanne",
  last_name: "Kate",
  location: "London"
}]
const result = {};

arr.map(item => {
  result[item.location] = [];
  return item;
}).map(item => {
  result[item.location].push(Object.values(item));
});

let res2 = [];
Object.keys(result).forEach((key, index) => {
  res2[index] = result[key]
});
console.log(res2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll save this for further projects.