# Firebase Angular - Sort my user by value - sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase and Angular, here is my database with my users :

[image: Picture of my database]

I want to sort my user by "ptsTotal".

I have a users.service with a function getUsersByPoints. But when I'm using it the console return to me :
this.users.sort is not a function.

I don't see where I'm doing a mistake. could you help me to find the mistake or give me another solution to sort my user ?

Thanks a lot,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../models/user.model';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  users: User[] = [];
  usersSubject = new Subject<User[]>();

  constructor() { }

  emitUsers(){
    this.usersSubject.next(this.users);
  }

  saveUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users').set(this.users);
  }

  getUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users')
    .on('value',(data)=>{
      this.users = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
      this.users.sort((a,b)=>a.ptsTotal-b.ptsTotal);
      this.emitUsers();
    });
  }
```

Comment: It looks like firebase is changing this.users into an object, so its prototype would no longer include sort.

Answer (score 1):

`data.val()` is not going to be an array.  It's a going to be an object whose properties are the named the same as child keys under users (e.g. "-M9YJ...").  Those properties will further contain the data under each child.

If you need to sort by a child value, Realtime Database can actually do that for you using `orderByChild()` as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).  You don't need to sort in the client.

If you do still want to sort in the client, you will have to [convert that object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript) somehow, then apply the sort to that new array.

Comment: Hello @Doug. Thank you, I'm almost sure that orderByChild is the good method to use. But it seems my id "M9YJ..." is a problem. When I'm doing orderByChild('ptsTotal') it's not working. And like I want all the users to establish a ranking I can't do an orderByChild('Id/ptsTotal'). What would be the solution ?