# Undefined is not a function when map array

Tags: arrays, react-native, dictionary

Data Array(trytArr) look that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/afxUI.png

I try map array from state:

```
  {
                trytArr.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <Hehe
                      key={i}
                      Procent={item.Procent}
                      />
                  );
                })
     }
```

I get:
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...dopasowanieArr.map...')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot of `dopasowanieArr`, it is an `Object`.

Then, you're trying to use `map()` on the Object.  `map()` can only be used on collections, like `Array`s.

Judging by the name of it (`dopasowanieArr`), you're expecting it to be an array, so you can convert the data you're getting to an array using the following (assuming that your data is returning a single object like your screenshot shows):

```
const data = documentSnapshot.data()
setDopasowanieArr(
  Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])
);
```

If you really are expecting it to be an array, I'd probably also consider starting with `useState([])` instead of `useState()` since you already have a `loading` state as well (which should probably be `useState(true)` instead of `useState("true")` as you currently have.

Comment: Amazing <3 but props doesn't works:
Procent={item.Procent}
tested with: Procent="smth" works.

Comment: Look at what your object has in it -- Procent is inside another key (I can't copy and paste it since you included an image and not text).  So, it would be something like asideasdfasdf.Procent.

Comment: ok, but I want to foreach element with ex. "ppN2vRyyffVMMbK5YB2iv67PWiG2" not object which we add to array in: setDopasowanieArr([documentSnapshot.data()]);
https://i.imgur.com/E78SsJd.png

Comment: Okay, then you need to turn your `Object` into an array based on its keys/values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript  I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: By the way, it seems like you have a mismatch between what your query is getting and what you expect to see. You keep expecting an array, but your query is returning a single document. You might need to look into the logic you're using for your query and how it relates to your Firestore structure

Comment: Amazing <3 Thank you very much <3