# How to convert an object into array and add keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I convert an object like:

```js
{
  "28fca3e7-7b5a-95b1-205c-03ff199dc2b4": 6,
  "426fb283-6fa9-a58c-e896-f795a5d42c50": 8,
  "629fe212-0d74-f5ce-d476-baa527252ffb": 12,
}
```

Into an array like:

```js
[{
  "id": "28fca3e7-7b5a-95b1-205c03ff199dc2b4",
  "count": 6
},
{
  "id": "629fe212-0d74-f5ce-d476-baa527252ffb",
  "count": 8
},
{
  "id": "426fb283-6fa9-a58c-e896-f795a5d42c50",
  "count": 12,
}]
```

I want to specifically add the keys "id" and "count" to the elements in each object of the array.

I have already converted the object to an array using this code:-

```js
Object.keys(arr).map(key => ({[key]: arr[key]}));
```

And the result is this:-

```js
[
  {
    "28fca3e7-7b5a-95b1-205c-03ff199dc2b4": 6,
  },

  {
    "629fe212-0d74-f5ce-d476-baa527252ffb": 8,
  },

  {
    "426fb283-6fa9-a58c-e896-f795a5d42c50": 12,
  },
]
```

I would like to add the above-mentioned keys("id" and "count") to this array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an Object {} to an Array \[\] of key-value pairs in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You may use **"getOwnPropertyName"** to get all keys of object and assign them to a list or array. Let me know if my answer is helpful!

```
var text = {
    "28fca3e7-7b5a-95b1-205c-03ff199dc2b4": 6,
    "426fb283-6fa9-a58c-e896-f795a5d42c50": 8,
    "629fe212-0d74-f5ce-d476-baa527252ffb": 12};

var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.text);

keys.forEach(x => {
      let newKeyObject = new keyObject();
      newKeyObject.key = x;
      newKeyObject.count = this.text[x];
      this.keyObjectList.push(newKeyObject);
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.keyObjectList));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than mapping from the keys is map Object.entries()

```js
const data = {
  "28fca3e7-7b5a-95b1-205c-03ff199dc2b4": 6,
  "426fb283-6fa9-a58c-e896-f795a5d42c50": 8,
  "629fe212-0d74-f5ce-d476-baa527252ffb": 12,
}, 

res = Object.entries(data).map(([id, count]) => ({id, count}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
const obj = {
  "28fca3e7-7b5a-95b1-205c-03ff199dc2b4": 6,
  "426fb283-6fa9-a58c-e896-f795a5d42c50": 8,
  "629fe212-0d74-f5ce-d476-baa527252ffb": 12,
};

const arr = Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({
  id: k,
  count: obj[k],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the keys you want and put those values on there. try this.

```
Object.keys(arr).map(key => ({"id":key, "count": arr[key]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll use the `Object.keys()` iterator to get an array of keys, and then transform that array into an array of objects.

```
const obj = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: 3,
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({id: key, count: obj[key]})));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) combined with `Array#map` like this

```js
const object = {"28fca3e7-7b5a-95b1-205c-03ff199dc2b4":6,"426fb283-6fa9-a58c-e896-f795a5d42c50":8,"629fe212-0d74-f5ce-d476-baa527252ffb":12,};

const result = Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => ({Id: key, count: value}));
console.log(result);
```

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable string-keyed property `[key, value] pairs`

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @Suprateek Korukonda https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers