# How to turn an object into an array using map()?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function that captures images from the camera and gallery, but when choosing an image or capturing a photo my function is returning an object, I need to use map() so that it returns an array containing all the information from the image's URI . How could I implement map() in this case?

This is my function:

```
const [uriImg, setUriImg] = useState('');

function imagePickerCallback(data) {

if (data.didCancel) {
    return;
  }

  if (data.error) {
    return;
  }

  if (!data.uri) {
    return;
  }
  setUriImg(data);
  
}
```

This is where I call the function

```
<Image 
    source = {{
    uri: uriImg
    ? uriImg.uri
    : 'https://socialistmodernism.com/wpcontent/uploads/2017/07/placeholder-image.png?w=640'}}
    style={styles.placeholderImage}
 />

      <View style={styles.optionsCamera}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() =>
          ImagePicker.launchCamera({},imagePickerCallback)
          }>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Abrir câmera</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() =>
          ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({},imagePickerCallback)
          }>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Escolher imagem</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

This is what appears in the console when choosing or capturing an image,  an object.

LOG  {"assets": [{"fileName": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_bbd3b196-997f-4227-80aa-f0d86824969a.jpg", "fileSize": 622543, "height": 2289, "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.francaservices/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_bbd3b196-997f-4227-80aa-f0d86824969a.jpg", "width": 2289}]}

Comment: If you have a JS Object then .map() is not a function. Instead I suggest looking at using ```Object.entries(...)```

Comment: how could I use Object.entries (...)? I'm new to react-native and I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: Does the image picker select only 1 file at a time? If yes try this `setUriImg(data.assets[0].uri)`

Comment: @Paloma i'll try post an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an Object {} to an Array \[\] of key-value pairs in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved only with:

```
data.assets[0]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript Object type does not have a `.map()` function. Instead you can iterate through an Object using `Object.entries(...)` to get the keys and value. There are multiple ways to do this:

```js
data = {"assets": [{"fileName": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_bbd3b196-997f-4227-80aa-f0d86824969a.jpg", "fileSize": 622543, "height": 2289, "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.francaservices/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_bbd3b196-997f-4227-80aa-f0d86824969a.jpg", "width": 2289}]}
array = [] // A new array to store the values

// Assume 'data' is the object returned when an image is updated
Object.entries(data.assets[0]).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   array.push([key, value]); // Stores each key and value as an array pair
});

// Map over the new array printing out the keys and values
array.map(val => {console.log("Key:",val[0]+",","Value:",val[1])})
```

Comment: Good night, I tried using the code and it didn't work.
I need to select images from the gallery or take pictures with the camera, the image I gave is just an example.
I used the code and I'm still receiving an object, I don't know if I'm using it correctly.

Basically, I can take the picture and select the image, but when I call the image's URI it should come as an array and not an object, so when I call the image it doesn't appear visually to the user.