# API call using react Js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a table with different crypto currencies and their values using react and coingecko api.  I am new to api and api calls and every time i make a call i keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`.

```
     const [crypData, setCrypData] = useState([]);
    
      const apiGet = () =>{
        fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchange_rates') 
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok){
                return response.json()
            }
             throw response;
        })
        .then(res => {
            
            console.log(res); 
            setCrypData(res.data); 
            console.log("crypData"); 
    
           });
        };
    
    
      useEffect(() => { 
        apiGet();
      },[])
     
    return ( 
            <>
            {crypData.map(item =>
                <tr > 
                    <td scope="row">{item.rates.btc.name} </td> 
                    <td>{item.rates.btc.unit} </td>
                    <td>{item.rates.btc.value} </td>  
                    <td>
                        {item.rates.btc.type} 
                        <button type="button"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )} 
            </>
         );
    }
     
    export default DataTables;
```

When i change the response i am still getting this TypeError: crypData.map is not a function

```
       .then(res => {
           
           console.log(res); 
           setCrypData(res); 
           console.log("crypData"); 
   
          });
```

Comment: What does this log to the console?: `console.log(res);`  When I make a request to that API, I don't see a `data` property.  Or any array at all.

Comment: this logs to show response from fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchange_rates') without changing to list

Comment: Could be that it's a lifecycle issue, before calling the api or before it sets the value to the state the component wants to render. When you used the second part did the data printed to the console seem ok?

Comment: @PaulBarasa: Where specifically in that response are you seeing a `data` property?  Or any kind of array on which to call `.map()`?

Comment: yes the data seems okay until i try to add to  setCrypData(res.data);

Answer (score 0):

A critical part of your debugging is to examine the actual response from the server.
Edited for brevity but structurally the same, that response is:

```
{
   "rates":{
      "btc":{
         "name":"Bitcoin",
         "unit":"BTC",
         "value":1.0,
         "type":"crypto"
      },
      "eth":{
         "name":"Ether",
         "unit":"ETH",
         "value":14.367,
         "type":"crypto"
      },
      "ltc":{
         "name":"Litecoin",
         "unit":"LTC",
         "value":277.933,
         "type":"crypto"
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, there is no `data` property at the root of the object.  So `res.data` is `undefined`.  And you can't call `.map()` on `undefined`.  Additionally, there is no array, only an object.  And you can't call `.map()` on an object because it's not a function on objects.

Your `res` object in the API result has a single property called `rates`, which is an object containing many properties, all of which have the same object structure.  If you want to `.map()` over those properties then you're first going to need to [convert them to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38824349/328193).  Then you would pass that *array* to `setCrypData()` to update your state.

Comment: Thank you verry much i was solve my problem using what you pointed out thanks again for your help