# TypeScript gives error when calling .size on a map in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary

I'm writing a React Component where I pass a map in as a prop and read the size of it later. When I type the map with TypeScript, I get no errors, but I get an error when I call `.size` on the map. In addition, when I try to map over that array, I get an error as well.

The map itself contains key and value pairs, both of which are strings.

Code:

```
import * as Styled from './assignments-list.styles'

type TMap<T> = {
    [index: string] : T
}

type TAssignmentsListProps = {
    assignments: TMap<string>
}

const AssignmentsList = ({assignments}: TAssignmentsListProps) => {

    return (
        <Styled.AssignmentsList>
            <Styled.Header> 
                Assignments
            </Styled.Header>
                {
                    (assignments && assignments.size !== 0) ? // error here
                    <Styled.ListFiles>
                        {
                            Array.from(assignments).map(([name, url]) => { // error here
                                return (
                                    <li key={name}> 
                                        <Styled.ListItemWrapper>
                                            <Styled.FileName>
                                                {name}
                                            </Styled.FileName>
                                            <Styled.RemoveFile>
                                                View
                                            </Styled.RemoveFile>
                                        </Styled.ListItemWrapper>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </Styled.ListFiles> :
                    <Styled.BodyText>None</Styled.BodyText>
                }
        </Styled.AssignmentsList>
    )
}

export default AssignmentsList
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is this error message?

Comment: There is no [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in your code. You have no `size` property defined for your type. You have no `[Symbol.iterator]` method for your type, so it will not work with `Array.from`. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what is the real type of the `assignments`

Here error `assignments.size !== 0` because you are trying to compare a string with a number, which is always false.

If can be fixed, by fixing type

```typescript
type TMap<T> = {
  [index: string]: T
} & {
  size: number
}
```

or

```typescript
type TMap<T> = Map<string, T>
```

Or if it map of string, you can check map size with

```typescript
assignments && Object.keys(assignments).length !== 0
```

Converting your map to array depending on real map type.
If it `Map` then `Array.from` should work

If it map of string you can use [How to convert an Object {} to an Array [] of key-value pairs in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm about 75% sure the OP meant to use an actual [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (which has a size and works out of the box with `Array.from`).