# Create array of objects for a select based on items from a data table

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, vuetify.js, v-select

So I have a data table in Vuetify that's containing eventlog items. For example, it looks like this:

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "actionBy": "John",
        "eventAction": "CREATED",
        "Description": ""
        "actionDate": "2022-09-02T10:31:57.223765"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "actionBy": "Anna",
        "eventAction": "MODIFIED",
        "Description": ""
        "actionDate": "2022-09-07T13:44:29.892831"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "actionBy": "Eric",
        "eventAction": "REMOVE_IMAGE",
        "Description": "Test description"
        "actionDate": "2022-09-07T13:44:39.800381"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "actionBy": "Sysadmin",
        "eventAction": "REMOVE_IMAGE",
        "Description": "Test description"
        "actionDate": "2022-09-08T09:21:29.272312"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "actionBy": "Sysadmin",
        "eventAction": "MODIFIED",
        "Description": "Test description"       
        "actionDate": "2022-09-08T09:21:54.991851"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "actionBy": "Sysadmin",
        "eventAction": "REMOVE_IMAGE",
        "Description": "Test description"       
        "actionDate": "2022-09-08T13:55:00.469676"
    }
]
```

Now I want to use a select(in Vuetify it's a v-select). Where I want to get the select options like this:

```
[
  { value: 'CREATED', count: 1 },
  { value: 'MODIFIED', count: 2 },
  { value: 'REMOVE_IMAGE', count: 3 },
]
```

I found some ways, but it doesn't feel really clean. I want to know if there is a efficient way to do this. So it doesn't look dirty. ;-)

Comment: How do you expect to generate the text "image removed"?

Comment: Got a function for that. Like:

    displayTypeText(item)
    witch (item.eventAction) {
      case 'CREATED':
        return 'created';
 case 'MODIFIED':
        return 'modified';
 case 'REMOVE_IMAGE:
        return 'image removed';
`

Comment: Removed the text. To prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: Use one of the groupbys [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) and then convert the object to an array using Object.keys like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a group by from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/8170844) and a mapping from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38824395/8170844) to create an array:

```
computed: {
    selectOptions() {
        const obj = this.events.reduce((ar, x) => {
           ar[x.eventAction] = (ar[x.eventAction] || 0) + 1;
           return ar;
        }, {});
        return Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({value: key, count: obj[key]}));
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic! That is really clean. My attempt had like 20 rows of code..  ^_^
Thank you!